# Removing JOptionPane Icon

Tags: java

Using this code, the icon is not removed

```
int returnValue = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Successfully Updated", "Message",
                  JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 0, null, buttons, buttons[0]);
```

Im not yet allowed to upload images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified the message type in the wrong parameter field.

Your code should look something like this.

```
int returnValue = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Successfully Updated", "Message",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, buttons, buttons[0]);
```

The 'JOptionpane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION' can be changed to whatever you want, I messed around with it a bit and it did not seem to matter what it was for the use you gave it.

The new option dialog will look something like this (From when I ran it with the above code).

[image]